# Rails 3.2 - Ajax call when text field changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ujs

I have a Rails 3.2.13 app with some Ajax on *forms* and *links*, using the *remote* parameter.
The problem is that i can't find in the docs how to do the same with *text fields* - the
*remote* parameter didn't work, so i think it's not supported on input objects.

I'd like to do bind 'ajax:xxx' events (like 'ajax:success') on my text_field objects.
I this even possible with UJS? If not, what my options are?

Here's some code:

```
<%= form_for @post, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>    
<div class = 'control-group'>
    <%= f.label :title, :html => {:class => 'control-label'} %>     
    <%= f.text_field :title, :placeholder => 'Title', :class => 'input-xxlarge' %>
</div>

<div class = 'control-group'>
    <%= f.label :body, :html => {:class => 'control-label'} %>      
    <%= f.text_area :body, :placeholder => 'Your post here', :class => 'input-xxlarge', 
    :rows => 15 %>
</div>

<div class = 'control-group'>
    <%= f.label :tags, :html => {:class => 'control-label'} %>      
    <%= f.text_field :tags, :placeholder => 'Tags separeted by ,', :class => 'input-xxlarge', 
    :value => '' %>
</div>

<%= f.submit 'Create', :class => 'btn btn-primary'%>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would bind a `change` or `blur` event to the `input`, and then make the `Ajax` call manually on your `javascript/coffecript` file.

`posts.js`

```
$('#post_title').change(function() {
  // Do your stuff, instantiate variables, etc...
  $.ajax({
    type: post_or_get,
    url: your_url,
    data: your_data,
    success: function(data) {
      // Handle stuff after hitting the server here
    },
    error: function(data) {
    }
  });
});
```